# How do you stop particle objects from a collection intersecting with each other?

Tags: particles, collision

I'm trying to create a scene with a bunch of flying cars.  I have 5 different car models in a collection and I've set up a rectangular emitter and a path for the traffic to follow.  That all works fine , but is there any way to stop the cars from intersecting each other, short of trial and error with lifetime and number of objects?
[image]

Comment: short answer: you can't